# Pass data to remote in jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I pass additional data to server with remote request in jquery validate.
I tried doing something like this, and it's not resulting as expected.

```
personal_email: {
  email: true,
  remote: {
    param: {
      url: app.baseurl('user/check_personal_email'),
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'userID': $('#id').val()
      }
    }
  }
},
```

How do I pass the data?

Comment: Just read the docs and look at the example code here:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: @Sparky thank you... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with a function and return?

```
data: {
  'userID': function(){ 
     return $('#id').val(); 
   }
}
```